# Is it possible to use LinqPad's Hyperlinq() method to create a link to a file path

Tags: linqpad

I really like how Hyperlinq allows you to hyperlinq to a website, but what about to a file?  I would like to do something like this:

```
new Hyperlinq(@"C:\temp\afile.txt");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bug in LINQPad - I've fixed it for the next build.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried

```
new Hyperlinq(new Uri(@"C:\temp\afile.txt").ToString());
```

With this you get a valid hyperlink but I failed to click on it to open the file.

If you paste the link into a browser it works.  I don't know if its a limitation of LinqPad.

Comment: Did you actually create the file? It does have to exist so your hyperlinq can open it.

Comment: It did exists.  I haven't tried if this was fix in a more recent version of LinqPad